# p-значимость в статистике

Tags: статистика, статический-анализ

Разбираю статью о ковиде, не сильна в статистике, как трактовать p-значение( понимаю, что p > .05 статистически значимо, p < .05 статистически не значимо), но почему пишут >.99, если сравнивая с .05, должен быть знак < (.5 < .99), подскажите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Безотносительно даже что такое `p-value` значения в столбце таблицы `PValue` нужно трактовать так:

- `.20` означает `p-value = 0.2`
- `< 0.001` означает `p-value < 0.001`
- `> .99` означает `p-value > 0.99`

Смысл указания тут знаков "больше" и "меньше" в том, что значения меньше скольки-то и больше скольки-то не имеет уже смысла писать прямо точно, это граница, дальше которой уточнять значения смысла нет.